# Formatting number as fixed-length binary in python when number is larger than number of bits

Tags: python, string, binary, formatting

I am trying to convert a number to its binary representation with a fixed length. I have tried using

```
>>> "{0:04b}".format(number)
```

which works when the number can be fully represented in four bits (0-15), however I need the string to always be four bits long, even if the number is out of range. For example,

```
>>> "{0:04b}".format(17)
```

should return '0001', not '10001'.

I am aware I can just index the last 4 bits of the resulting string, however I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: `"{0:04b}".format(number & 0xF)` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general method to limit the width of an integer conversion. However, you may want to use a specific method for your specific case.

If you don't want to reduce the string after it is generated, you could reduce the input number. Since you are only interested in the low-order four bits, `& 0xf` should isolate those for you:

```
"{0:04b}".format(number & 0xF)
```

Alternatively, you could invoke `format` twice, once to convert the integer and once to limit the field width of the resulting string. This is fairly unreadable, so I wouldn't recommend it:

```
"{0:4.4s}".format("{0:04b}".format(number))
```